# An identity for diagonal matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, diagonalization

I have recently seen use of the following identity:

> $ ADA^T = D A^T A  $ where A is a real rectangular matrix and D is a real diagonal matrix.

Does this necessarily hold? Or is it the other way around?
I thank all helpers.

Comment: No, it doesn't hold.  Have you tried checking any examples?

Comment: Maybe I made a numeric error, but seing as how I multiply by a diagonal matrix is there some way I can "move" the diagonal matrix?

Comment: In general, we should not expect that "moving matrices" will work in that way.

Comment: If every diagonal elements of the diagonal matrix are equal, then the matrix can commute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that what you have seen is associated with "trace" function; more precisely, it is likely to be a particular case of the **cyclic invariance of the trace**:

$$trace(A*B*C)=trace(B*C*A)$$

see (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trace_(linear_algebra))